# Why can't this code be executed?

Tags: c, pointers, graph, linked-list, adjacency-list

I was working on graph insertion using a linked list. The code below is working fine as expected.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#define new_node (struct node*)malloc(sizeof(struct node))

struct node {
    int index;
    struct node* next;
};

void addEdge(struct node* head, int parent, int child) {
    struct node* temp = new_node;
    temp->index = child;
    temp->next = (head+parent)->next;
    (head+parent)->next = temp;

    struct node* tmp = new_node;
    tmp->index = parent;
    tmp->next = (head+child)->next;
    (head+child)->next = tmp;
    return;
}

struct node* create_graph( int v ) {
    struct node* temp = ( struct node* )malloc( v*sizeof(struct node) );
    for( int i = 0; i < v; i++ ) {
        (temp+i)->index = i;
        (temp+i)->next = NULL;
    }

    return temp;
}

void printGraph(struct node* head, int vertex) {
    struct node* temp;
    for( int i = 0; i < vertex; i++ ) {
        printf("All nodes connected to node %d is ", (head+i)->index);
        temp = (head + i)->next;
        while(temp != NULL) {
            printf("-> %d", temp->index);
            temp = temp->next;
        }
        printf("\n");
    }
}

int main(void) {
    int v; // Number of vertex in graph.
    struct node* head = NULL;
    v = 5;
    //scanf( "%d", &v );
    head = create_graph( v );
    addEdge(head, 0, 1);
    addEdge(head, 0, 4);
    addEdge(head, 1, 2);
    addEdge(head, 1, 3);
    addEdge(head, 1, 4);
    addEdge(head, 2, 3);
    addEdge(head, 3, 4);
    printGraph(head, 5);
    return 0;
}
```

But if I update the following changes in the `printGraph` function, the code results in a **Runtime Error**.

```
void printGraph(struct node* head, int vertex) {
    struct node* temp = head;
    for( int i = 0; i < vertex; i++ ) {
        printf("All nodes connected to node %d is ", (temp+i)->index);
        temp = (temp+i)->next; 
        while(temp != NULL) {
            printf("-> %d", temp->index);
            temp = temp->next;
        }
        printf("\n");
    }
}
```

The following line is the main issue that I can't wrap my mind around:
Why does this line lead the code to a runtime error?

```
temp = (temp+i)->next;
```

P.S. Compiler used is `GCC 6.3`.

Comment: Please include the exact error message; ``temp+i`` is probably not a valid memory address.

Comment: @PhilippLudwig SIGSEGV is the error message.

Comment: you're attempting to use `temp` for two purposes at the same time : for iterating over the `head` array, and for iterating through the linked lists. You can't do both with one variable - you need two variables.

Comment: @SanderDeDycker I understood the error I was making and thanks for your comment.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The error is in the inside `while` loop you've reached to the `temp == NULL` to quit the `while` loop and in the first line of the outer `for` loop calling `(temp + i)->index`. As `temp` is null, you are getting the error.

However, in the first code, you are using `head` instead of `temp` at the beginning of the outer loop (in contrast with the second case which is using `temp`). Hence, you change the value of the `temp` base on the `head` and you have not any problem with the null value of `temp` in contrast with the second case.

To resolve this, you can initiate another variable like `temp` as `new_temp` to use inside the inner `while` loop and distinguish between the logic of the inner and outside loop.

Comment: First of all, thank you for taking the time to answer my query, can you please explain how and how that's different from the above( correct ) code.

Comment: Thanks a lot. Now I'm able to understand why I was getting the error( which was actually a silly one).